# Tableau aggregate functions returning wrong values

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to calculate the sum of Impressions and Clicks by AdGroupId in Tableau. Tableau is returning wrong values of summation for several AdGroupIds although the underlying data seems to be perfectly fine.

Refer attached images - the sum of impressions and clicks for the given AdGroupId is clearly wrong.

[image: Calculated sum of clicks and impressions]

[image: Underlying Data]

Can anyone point out the issue or suggest what can be done in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Before building a view, convert AdGroupId to dimension.  From your screenshot it is clear that the field is a measure.

Ids are sometimes stored as numbers. Tableau automatically convert numbers to measure. But i don't think there will ever be need to calculate sum(id) or average of id.

Count you can calculate from dimensions too. It is therefore advisable to convert these type of dimension fields to dimension/string data type at the time of importing the data in Tableau. Hope this clarifies

Comment: That makes sense. However, is there any real difference if I convert it into a dimension every time I pull it to the columns/rows pane versus converting it to a dimension before building the view altogether?

Comment: Is your problem still unsolved? You have neither accepted the answer nor upvoted it.  Please tell

Comment: > Sorry for the delayed response, was OOO the last 2 days. Unfortunately the problem still seems to persist. I'm in touch with a tableau representative and we're still investigating. Will let you know if we figure something out

Comment: Ok.  Good luck.  By the way can you please show me the 'summary' tab of show data window

Comment: The issue turned out to be a glitch. Would you need that summary data anyway?